# Limit of the prime factors of the integer n over n

Tags: real-analysis

The function $v(n)$ yields the number of prime factors of integer n.

$v(8) = 3, v(5) = 1$

Prove the limit

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac {v(n)}{n} = 0$

I have some sort of intuition since the numbers with the highest prime factors come in the form of $2^n$ so 2 4 8 16 ...
The distance between them gets bigger and bigger as n uniformly increases so the limit makes some sense.

I don't know, however, how I would be able to put this intuition in rigorous terms. Can someone help me out?

Comment: $v(n)\le \log_2(n)$

Comment: $n=p_{1}^{a_{1}}...p_{s}^{a_{s}}\geq 2^{s}=2^{v(n)}$.